# Force ansible to fail (return non-zero code) if there are any 'changed' tasks

Tags: ansible, integration-testing

I want to a perform convergence test for a playbook. Convergence test checks if second run of the same playbook make no changes.

Is there a way to say Ansible "make exit code non-zero if there was a task in 'changed' state?". I can parse stdout, but it's ugly.

Example:

```
set -e
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml site.yaml  # normal run
ansible-playbook --help-me-here -i inventory.yaml site.yaml  # should return non-zero if anything changed.
```

Comment: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/testing-ansible-roles-travis-ci-github#role-idempotence

Comment: [molecule](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/blob/master/README.rst) basically adopts the same strategy as above when running the idempotency step: https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/blob/9f9e206c3a80a088f0855782c53c3b329e2eb45d/molecule/command/idempotence.py#L94

Answer (score 1):

Another option than the one I put into the comments is to use [`molecule`](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It automatically sets up linters as well as syntax-, unit- and idempotence tests. I found it to be most useful when developing [ansible-role-sssh](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/ansible-role-sssh), although molecule has dropped vagrant support since then.

```
$ python3 -m venv ./role-devel
$ source ./role-devel/bin/activate
$ pip install "molecule[lint,docker]"
[...]
$ molecule init role  yourrole
--> Initializing new role yourrole...
Initialized role in /path/to/yourrole successfully.
```

Now edit your `tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
# tasks file for yourrole
- debug:
    var=ansible_date_time.iso8601
- name: Update motd
  template:
    src: "motd.j2"
    dest: "/etc/motd"
```

and create `templates/motd.j2`:

```
THIS SYSTEM IS PROUDLY MANAGED BY ANSIBLE SINCE {{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}
```

Now, when you run your tests, molecule will run an idempotence check and recognize that `Update motd` has changed both in the first and second run. Thus, the idempotence test will fail:

```
$ molecule test

[...]

--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'converge'

    PLAY [Converge] ****************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    ok: [instance]

    TASK [Include yourrole] ********************************************************

    TASK [yourrole : debug] ********************************************************
    ok: [instance] => {
        "ansible_date_time.iso8601": "2020-03-21T11:31:05Z"
    }

    TASK [yourrole : Update motd] **************************************************
    changed: [instance]

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    instance                   : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'idempotence'
ERROR: Idempotence test failed because of the following tasks:
* [instance] => yourrole : Update motd
An error occurred during the test sequence action: 'idempotence'. Cleaning up.

[...]

$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I really appreciate your input, but I've specifically say 'playbooks'. We have integration tests (when everything is run at once against staging) and I need to see convergence for the whole playbook, not for a single role.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html) there is no straightforward option to do this,

You can do the following,

Create a boolean variable that tracks if *changed* should be considered a failure.
Evaluate the control inside the playbook.

#### For example, in your playbook you can handle the flag like so,

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "Test message"
#   This task reports 'changed' always because we set changed_when to True
    changed_when: True
    register: result
#   We can control whether or not to fail the task if task reports changed. 
#   The task fails if 
#     it actually fails or 
#     when it changes and when we ask it to consider change as a failure
#   Note: Defaults to understand changed just means changed and not failed
    failed_when:
      - result is failed or (result.changed and changed_means_failure|default(False)|bool)
```

## Execute your playbook

```
set -e

ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml site.yaml  # normal run
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "changed_means_failure=True" -i inventory.yaml site.yaml  # should return non-zero if anything changed.
```